# How to apply an empty condition to sql select by using "and" in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an UuidConditionSet, when the if condition is wrong, I want apply an empty string to my select statement(or just ignore this UuidConditionSet), but I got this error. How to solve this problem?

```
mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 10, pos 3)
```

This is the select

```
(SELECT
 item,
 amount,
 date
 from my_table
 where record_type = 'myType'
 and ( date_format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= '2020-02-27'
 and  date_format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd") <= '2020-02-28' )
 and ()
```

```
var UuidConditionSet = ""
var UuidCondition = Seq.empty[String]
    if(!UuidList.mkString.isEmpty) {
    UuidCondition = for {
        Uuid <- UuidList
        UuidConditionSet = s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.UUID} = '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'")
        } yield UuidConditionSet
    UuidConditionSet = UuidCondition.reduce(_.concat(" or ").concat(_))
}


    s"""SELECT
        | ${SQLColumnHelper.STRUCT_NAME_ITEM},
        | ${SQLColumnHelper.STRUCT_NAME_AMOUNT},
        | ${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}
        | from ${sqlTableHelper.TABLE}
        | where ${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME} = '${RECORD_TYPE}'
        | and ( date_format(${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}, "${Constant.STAY_DATE_FORMAT}") >= '${stayDateRangeTuple._1}'
        | and  date_format(${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}, "${Constant.STAY_DATE_FORMAT}") <= '${stayDateRangeTuple._2}' )
        | and ($UuidConditionSet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern matching on the list `UuidList` to check the size and return an empty string if the list is empty. Also, you can use `IN` instead of multiple `OR`s here.

Try this:

```
val UuidCondition = UuidList match {
  case l if (l.size > 0) => {
    l.map(u => s"'$u'").mkString(
        s"and ${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.UUID} in (",
        ",",
        ")"
      )
  }
  case _ => ""
}

s"""SELECT
  | ${SQLColumnHelper.STRUCT_NAME_ITEM},
  | ${SQLColumnHelper.STRUCT_NAME_AMOUNT},
  | ${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}
  | from ${sqlTableHelper.TABLE}
  | where ${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME} = '${RECORD_TYPE}'
  | and date_format(${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}, "${Constant.STAY_DATE_FORMAT}") >= '${stayDateRangeTuple._1}'
  | and date_format(${SQLColumnHelper.DATE}, "${Constant.STAY_DATE_FORMAT}") <= '${stayDateRangeTuple._2}'
  | $UuidCondition
"""
```